# Laravel: Query on the same table multiple times

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have a table of users

```
+-------+------+-----+
| User  | Sale | Sex |
+-------+------+-----+
| user1 |  120 | M   |
| user2 |   98 | M   |
| user3 |    5 | F   |
+-------+------+-----+
```

in laravel, we query this by the following statement:

```
$allMale = UserTable::where('Sex', 'M')->get();
```

What will happen in I try to query again on the same table

```
 $allFemales = UserTable::where('Sex', 'F')->get();
 $user1 = UserTable::where('User', 'user1')->get();
```

will it query 3 times? is it possible to query once and then Parse it multiple times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I'm not sure if UserTable here is Builder or Eloquent but Eloquet under the hood is using MySQL so it will run 3 different queries:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Sex = 'M';
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Sex = 'F';
SELECT * FROM users WHERE User = 'user1';
```

Of course you can do it like this:

```
$users = UserTable::where(function($q) {
  $q->whereIn('Sex', ['M', 'F'])->orWhere('User', 'user1')
})->get();
```

This will generate query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ((Sex IN ('M', 'F') OR USER = 'user1'))
```

and now you can get those users from variable like this using [Laravel collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections):

```
$allMale = $users->where('Sex', 'M')->get();
$allFemales = $users->where('Sex', 'F')->get();
$user1 = $users->where('User', 'user1')->get();
```

Now, assuming that user1 has sex set, you could in fact use:

```
$users = UserTable::whereIn('Sex', ['M', 'F'])->get();
```

In addition, assuming there is only single user1 instead of:

```
$user1 = $users->where('User', 'user1')->get();
```

probably better solution would be:

```
$user1 = $users->where('User', 'user1')->first();
```